# How do I iterate over the options of a SelectField in a template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a select field in the form and now I need to iterate over options in this field.

`{{ form.myselect }}` gives me this:

```
<select name="myselect" id="id_myselect">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="2">Item 1</option>
    <option value="3">Item 2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Now I need to add some attributes to the options and because of that what I need is:

```
<select name="myselect" id="id_myselect">
{% for x in form.myselect %}
    <option value="{{ x.id }}">{{ x.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

but there is an error:

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: 'BoundField' object is not iterable
```

I tried `form.myselect.all`, `form.myselect.option_set` but it gives nothing

Comment: So what you want is all the `<option>` without the `<select>` and no blank (`-----`) option? or did I miss something? ... What are you trying to achieve specifically here?

Comment: No I want to add some atributes to the options and because of that need it in the ` {% for x in form.myselect %}` loop somehow.

Comment: My suggestion would be to alter the widget and do it in the code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: Thanks James. I was hope that there is some way to iterate over options in template.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477856/how-to-add-attributes-to-option-tags-in-django

Comment: Thats something that really needs to be in the widget. IMHO its the right place also.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I've been struggling with this problem today and found the solution. Yes, you can iterate over options of the select tag directly in template. Here's how to do it in template:

```
<select id="id_customer" name="customer">
{% for x, y in form.fields.customer.choices %}
    <option value="{{ x }}"{% if form.fields.customer.value == x %} selected{% endif %}>{{ y }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

In this case I have a `customer` field in the form which has choices set up as follows:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    customer = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Customer')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customer'].choices = [(e.id, e.customer) for e in Customers.objects.all()]
```

Comment: I had the same issue and had success without changing anything else but adding: `{% for c in form.fields.customer.queryset %}<option value="{{ c.id }}">{{ c.name|capfirst }}</option>{% endfor %}`

Comment: To set the selected didn't work for me. Instead of `form.fields.Customer.value` I had to use `form.initial.Customer`

Answer (score 30):

Got it to work with:

```
    <select name="myselect" class="i-can-add-my-own-attrs-now" id="id_myselect">
        {% for id, name in form.myselect.field.choices %}
        <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

BUT REALLY, a better way to do this is with [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks):

```
    {% load widget_tweaks %}
    {{ form.myselect|add_class:"i-can-haz-custom-classes-easily" }}
```

Doing it with django-widget-tweaks will also set the default 'selected="selected"' for you, which is super nice!

Comment: but this only adds the class to a <select> itself  not each option field. Is it possible to iterate through choices with this plugin?

Answer (score 9):

I do this way:

```
<select id="id_construction_type" name="construction_type" class="form-control input-md">
{% for value, key in form_urban.fields.construction_type.choices %}
    <option value="{{ value }}"{% if form_urban.initial.construction_type == value %} selected {% endif %}>
        {{ key }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a cleaner solution, you can set the attributes using a custom Widget. This way you don't have to render the field manually:

```
class CustomSelectWidget(forms.Select):
    def create_option(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        option = super().create_option(name, value, *args, **kwargs)
        if value:
            instance = self.choices.queryset.get(pk=value)  # get instance
            option['attrs']['custom_attr'] = instance.field_name  # set option attribute
        return option

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    some_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=SomeModel.objects.all(),
        widget=CustomSelectWidget
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue several times and wanted to add an additional situation where you are using Django filters and setting choices that are related to a FieldFilter you've defined inside the FilterSet class.

```
class CustomFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    your_field = django_filters.CharFilter(
        field_name='your_field',
        lookup_expr='iexact',
        widget=forms.Select(
            choices=[(x, x) for x in some_list_of_choices]
        )
    )
```

The other solutions, rely on a `.choices` attribute on the `field` class but they did not work for me. Instead I iterated through the `your_field` attr on the `Form` associated with the `FilterSet`.

This allows you to easily set your own default and assign any desired classes to the select element.

```
<select name="your_field">
    <option value="" selected>Your Field</option>
    {% for option in filter.form.your_field %}
        {{ option }}
    {% endfor %}

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

With radio buttons in your template use.

```
    <table>
        {% for x,y in form.fields.Customer.choices %}
        <tr>
            <td><input id="id_Customer_{{x}}" {% if form.fields.Customer.value == x %}checked="checked"{% endif %} name="Customer" type="radio" value="{{x}}" /></td>
            <td>{{ y }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```