# Django add attributes to SelectMultiple <option> tags

Tags: python, django

There's a great explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477856/how-to-add-attributes-to-option-tags-in-django) on adding attributes to `<option>` tags within a django form field.  But this is only for a `Select` [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Select).  I want to do the same for a `SelectMultiple` [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#SelectMultiple).

I tried the following (subclass `Select` and `SelectMultiple` and reference `MySelectMultiple` when creating the `Model` form field `employees`):

```
class MySelect(forms.Select):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MySelect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        # original forms.Select code #
        return u'<option custom_attribute="foo">...</option>'

class MySelectMultiple(MySelect):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySelectMultiple, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

employees = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                    widget=MySelectMultiple(attrs={}),
                    queryset=Employee.objects.all(),
                )
```

But the rendered form is still showing as a `Select` widget, not a `SelectMultiple` widget.

I can provide `attrs={'multiple':'multiple'}` to `MySelectMultiple` to make the form field render as a multiple select widget - but when the form is saved, only a single value is saved (not multiple values)!

**How can I have the form render as a multiple choice field AND save all of the selected values?  Thank you.**

Comment: is employees field  a manytomany field

Comment: @Thameem yes.  But see answer below.

Comment: by default a manytomany field will render as a mutlipleselct field and when you call form.save(). it will automatically save those values. then why you using this

Comment: Yup, excellent point. But I am doing this to add additional attributes to the `<option>` tag - which the default `SelectMultiple` widget does not provide.

Comment: There is a general solution which works for Django 2.+ and allows to add a title and other things in options, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56097149/1788851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select multiple should inherit from `SelectMultiple` rather than `Select`:

```
class MySelectMultiple(SelectMultiple):
    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        # original forms.Select code #
        return u'<option custom_attribute="foo">...</option>'
```

It looks like your `__init__` method isn't necessary, since it just calls `super()`.

Comment: Let me give this a try. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer achieves the same outcome as my answer but mine violates DRY, so I'm going with yours.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SelectMultiple inherits from Select, you just need to override the create_option method to get the same results:

```
class MySelectMultiple(forms.SelectMultiple):
    def create_option(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        option = super().create_option(name, value, *args, **kwargs)
        if value:
            instance = self.choices.queryset.get(pk=value)  # get instance
            option['attrs']['custom_attr'] = instance.field_name  # set option attribute
        return option
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured out: by using:

```
class MySelectMultiple(MySelect):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySelectMultiple, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I was still using the django native `Select` but just calling it `MySelectMultiple`.  I needed to import the *rest* of `SelectMultiple`.

So, instead of:

```
class MySelectMultiple(MySelect):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySelectMultiple, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The class needs to be complete (copy/paste of native django code for `SelectMultiple`):

```
class MySelectMultiple(MySelect):
    allow_multiple_selected = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySelectMultiple, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if value is None:
            value = []
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        output = [format_html('<select multiple="multiple"{0}>', forms.utils.flatatt(final_attrs))]
        options = self.render_options(choices, value)
        if options:
            output.append(options)
        output.append('</select>')
        return mark_safe('\n'.join(output))

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        if isinstance(data, (MultiValueDict, MergeDict)):
            return data.getlist(name)
        return data.get(name, None)
```