# Subclassed Django SelectMultiple ignores any attribute set to its options

Tags: python, html, django, forms

following what I found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524214/django-add-attributes-to-selectmultiple-option-tags) I am trying to add a custom class to each option into the two `select` the widget produces.

I used the `FilteredSelectMultiple` admin widget, which is made of two list of elements the user can interact with to select one or more elements.

My relevant code:

```py
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class MySelectMultiple(FilteredSelectMultiple):
    def create_option(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        option = super().create_option(name, value, *args, **kwargs)
        print(option)
        option.update({'attrs': {'foo':'bar'}})  # set option attribute
        print(option)
        return option
```

```py
from django import forms
class MyReportForm(forms.Form):

    filters = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset= Item.objects.none(), # fixed below
        widget=MySelectMultiple("Item", is_stacked=True),
        required=False
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from myapp.utils import get_all_enabled_items

        super(MyReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # this returns a filtered queryset
        self.fields["filters"].queryset = get_all_enabled_items(lvl0=True)
```

The dictionary gets updated correctly if printed, but the form just ignores the attributes I set and produces the same HTML:

```
<select name="generic_filters" id="my_id_from" multiple="multiple" class="filtered" data-is-stacked="1">
<option value="1" title="myTitle1">myTitle1</option>
<option value="2" title="myTitle2">myTitle2</option>
<option value="3" title="myTitle3">myTitle3</option>
</select>
```

Please note that if I try to change the "value" using the same code (with `option.update({'value':'0'})`, the value correctly changes (and makes all the options have the same value!)

What am I doing wrong?

How do I set an attribute for each `select` `option` correctly?

The only thing I am trying to achieve is to give each option a conditional class name based on a property of the instance it represents, to style it differently with CSS.