# Django/jQuery Cascading Select Boxes in Admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-admin

I have a Contract class where *contract_mod* allows to extend a contract from a previous one. *contract_mod* should only show contracts related with the person that we selected previously. 
The Contract class returns the field *person*. As I've never work with AJAX/jQuery I don't know where to start.

So, my goal is that the field *contract_mod* depends on hte field *person* (using the Admin interface).

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    person        = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    contract_mod  = models.OneToOneField('self', blank = True, null = True) #allows to extend a contract
        ...
```

As the field contract_mod is OneToOneField I can't use django-smart-selects or django-ajax-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar situation I did the following (now adapted to your model):

## models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

class Contract(models.Model):
    person        = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    contract_mod  = models.OneToOneField('self', blank = True, null = True)
    contract_name = models.CharField(max_length=20) #just for testing

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_name() + " " +self.contract_name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.person.get_name() #to make sure you get the person name in the admin
    def contract_mod_name(self):
        if self.contract_mod:
            return self.contract_mod.contract_name
        else:
            return ""
```

## admin

```
class SelectField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def clean(self, value):
        return value

class CForm(forms.ModelForm):
    contracts_from_selected = SelectField()
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        widgets = { 'contract_mod' : forms.widgets.Select(attrs={'hidden' : 'true'}) }

class CAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CForm
    list_display = ('contract_name','get_name','contract_mod_name')#what you like
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if request.POST.get('contracts_from_selected'):
            obj.contract_mod=Contract.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('contracts_from_selected')))

        obj.save()
```

Override the change_form.html template (by copying it from the django/contrib/admin/templates/admin into your  yourapp/templates/admin/yourapp directory) and add the following Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#id_person").change(function () {    
        var options = $("#id_contract_mod option").filter(function () {
            return $(this).html().split(" ")[0] === $("#id_person   option:selected").html();
        }).clone();
        $("#id_contracts_from_selected").empty();
        $("#id_contracts_from_selected").append(options);
    });
});
```

One shortcoming is, that this uses the visible html entry to store the person - contract relation. So the person is also visible in the dropdown. To avoid this you could add an attribute to the options instead - see here:
[Django form field choices, adding an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089396/django-form-field-choices-adding-an-attribute)

Yes and it would be good to completely hide the contract_mod ChoiceField. Via the hidden=True in the widget only the dropdown is hidden.

Comment: It doesn't show any error but doesn't work yet. As I'm using Grappelli I take the change_form from its [directory](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/blob/master/grappelli/templates/admin/change_form.html) and I'm adding the function in the part of Javascript (should I put it in somewhere else?) Anyway, glad to know I'm not alone :)

Comment: If, I don't hide the widget, I can see it empty. @ger.s.brett

Comment: If it is empty the Javascript probably does not work. Can you check if the browser finds the Javascript (e.g. with Firebug or depending on what browser you use)? 
I have not worked with Grapelli (yet). I had put it on the bottom of the template just before the final {% endblock %} statement.

Comment: It works but shows the name in the field contracts_from_selected not in contract_mod

Comment: Yes that is the idea behind it. The valid selection options are loaded into the contracts_from_selected formfield.

Comment: Last thing: In CAdmin I want to get the attribute contracts_from_selected from CForm in order to use it in a fieldset. Is there any way to implemt a getter method? I'm trying with `return CForm.contracts_from_selected` and things like that without any results and I don't find documentation... Any suggestion?

Comment: The id of the selected contract you can get as shown above: Contract.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('contracts_from_selected'))). Is that what you need?

Comment: I didn't explain well. What I meant is that in admin.py, when I'm creating a fieldset with the fields that I want to be shown, I have to put the contracts_from_selected in order to see the results in the admin interface of Contract. `fieldsets = [
        [ None,
            {
                "fields" : [
                    ("contracts_from_selected")
                ]
            }
        ]`  But if I put it there I get an error so I guess I'll need a getter in CAdmin to import the values of contract_from_selected. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: One quick thought: you could define the contracts_from_selected in your model and leave it empy (null=True). Then you can use it in your fieldset. You only have to make sure that you set it always to Null when you save the model!