# Assign different CSS classes to Django ModelChoiceField from its queryset

Tags: python, django

I don't know if I am trying the impossible but I have HTML select option that comes from Django's forms.Form's queryset, `States.objects.all()`.

**Model**:

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

**Model**:

```
class States(models.Model):
    country_id = models.ForeignKey('Countries')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

**Form**:

```
class sign_up_form_school(forms.Form):
    states = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = States.objects.all(), 
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
          'class': states.country_id.name #is this POSSIBLE?
          }))
```

I want each select option value to have different class as I have tried above but it returns error: **name 'states' is not defined**.

Comment: Good question. Not related but I might point out that your form is a class, so you should follow python class naming convention, like `class SignUpSchoolForm`.

Comment: I personally don't think it's possible on the form level, but you can use javascript to dynamically add class name to the form, which I don't think would be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answer will also be answer to your problem: [Django form field choices, adding an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089396/django-form-field-choices-adding-an-attribute)
You would just need to add class instead of title and change rendering a bit.

Comment: No. It doesn't. It is an entirely different thing from what I want to achieve.