# Accessing Attributes of a CheckboxSelectMultiple checkbox

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

### **Short Version**

In the Django template language, how do I access the attributes of a given checkbox within a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget?

### **Long Version**

The attributes of a typical Django widget can be accessed easily:

```
{% for field in form %}
{{ field.widget.attrs.something }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, this method isn't working for a checkbox *within* a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget.

I have a customized `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget which I'm using to display a `ManyToMany` `ModelForm` field. The customized widget adds additional attributes to each checkbox in the `create_option` method.

The additional attributes display appropriately within the HTML of the input element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="questions" value="22" id="id_questions_12" category="Category Name" category_number="3" question="Question Name" question_number="4">
```

I need to access these additional attributes for purposes of display and organizing the form fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned back to this after letting it sit for a week or so. After playing around some more and reading into the docs for [BoundField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/boundfield/) (and `BoundWidget` specifically), I found out how to access the `attrs` of an individual checkbox in a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget:

```
{% for field in form %}
{% for check in field.subwidgets %}
{% for a in check.data.attrs %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the same technique given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56097149/12924930). It works perfectly for `CheckboxSelectMultiple` although it is not used in the answer.

I saved this in my project's `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple, Select


class SelectWithAttrs(Select):
    """
    Select With Option Attributes:
        Subclass of Django's Select widget that allows attributes in options,
        e.g. disabled="disabled", title="help text", class="some classes",
             style="background: color;", etc.

    Pass a dict instead of a string for its label:
        choices = [ ('value_1', 'label_1'),
                    ...
                    ('value_k', {'label': 'label_k', 'foo': 'bar', ...}),
                    ... ]
    The option k will be rendered as:
        <option value="value_k" foo="bar" ...>label_k</option>
    """

    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index,
                      subindex=None, attrs=None):
        if isinstance(label, dict):
            opt_attrs = label.copy()
            label = opt_attrs.pop('label')
        else:
            opt_attrs = {}
        option_dict = super().create_option(
            name, value, label, selected, index,
            subindex=subindex, attrs=attrs)
        for key, val in opt_attrs.items():
            option_dict['attrs'][key] = val
        return option_dict


class CheckboxSelectMultipleWithAttrs(
        SelectWithAttrs, CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    pass
```

Here is a working snippet from a project of mine that uses this example. The stuff in the beginning isn't really important, but it shows how to build your attributes dict and pass it into your `choices`.

```
from django import forms
from django.whatever import other_stuff

from project_folder import forms as project_forms


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['employees']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['employees'].queryset =\
            self.company.employee_set.filter(is_active=True)

        existing_crews_employees = []
        for crew in existing_job_crews:
            crew_employees =\
                [employee.__str__() for employee in crew.employees.all()]
            existing_crews_employees.append({'crew_name': crew.crewtype.name,
                                             'employees': crew_employees})

        employees_choices = []
        for (index, choice) in enumerate(self.fields['employees'].choices):
            # loop over each choice and set proper paramaters for employees
            # that are unassigned/on the current crew/on a different crew
            employee_in_crew = False

            employee_name = choice[1]
            for crew_and_employees in existing_crews_employees:
                for employee in crew_and_employees['employees']:
                    if employee_name == employee.__str__():
                        crew_name = crew_and_employees['crew_name']

                        if self.obj and self.obj.crewtype.name == crew_name:
                            # check the box if employee in current crew
                            employees_choices.append((choice[0], {
                                'label': choice[1],
                                'checked': True,
                                'id': f'id_employees_{choice[0].instance.id}'
                            }))
                        else:
                            # disable the choice if employee in another crew
                            employees_choices.append((choice[0], {
                                'label':
                                    employee_name + f" (on Crew: {crew_name})",
                                'disabled': True}))
                        employee_in_crew = True

            # for valid entries, ensure that we pass the proper ID
            # so that clicking the label will also check the box
            if not employee_in_crew:
                employees_choices.append((choice[0], {
                    'label': choice[1],
                    'id': f'id_employees_{choice[0].instance.id}'}))

        self.fields['employees'].widget = project_forms.CheckboxSelectMultipleWithAttrs(
            choices=employees_choices)
```

There are **two important things** to keep in mind when using this technique:

- Ensure that you pass the `id` into your attrs for your clickable options, otherwise your labels will not check the proper boxes when they are clicked.
- This method currently requires initial values to be set using the new attributes dict. Ensure that you pass the `'checked': True` key-value pair to any boxes that should be checked.